# What's the fundamental period of $f(x)=\cos(x)\cos(3x)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

I understand that $  f(x)=\cos(x)\cos(3x) $ is clearly periodic with a period of $T= 2\pi$ ($ T_1=2\pi, T_2=2\pi/3 ; T=3T_2=T_1=2\pi$). This is how I've learned to find a period of any $f(x)$ that consists of a sum/product of two functions... But is it actually useless when finding a fundamental period?

It's quite clear that $2\pi$ is a period of $f(x)$, but I can't understand how I can find the fundamental period of this function. The solution is supposed to be $\pi$ and it's obvious since $f(x+\pi)=f(x)$ in this case, but how do I find it algebraically?

I've searched through numerous answers and they wonderfully explain what a fundamental period actually is, but I understand that. I just don't know how to find it myself.

Comment: Using $\cos x\cos y=\frac 12\cos(x+y)+\frac12\cos(x-y)$, we find that $f(x)=\frac12\cos 2x+\frac12\cos 4x$; from $\gcd(2,4)=2$, it should be clear that $T_\min=\frac{2\pi}2$

Comment: Your method will give you the fundamental period when we *add* two functions. But, for the product of two functions, the calculated period might not be the fundamental one. The trick by Hagen to convert the product to the sum of sinusoidal functions is really useful in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it if you know what is the fundamental period of $\cos^2(x)$.

You have $f(x)=\cos(x) \cdot \cos(3x)=\cos^2(x)(4\cos^2(x)-3)$

How would you justify the fact that the fundamental period of $\cos^2(x)$ is $\pi$?